# woocommerce shipping method for specific city based on weight

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to make shipping method based on weight for specific city?

For example, I want to take the postage for city "A" for $1 per kg.

Here is the code of plugin I made:

```
public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
    $rate = array(
        'id' => $this->id,
        'label' => $this->title,
        'cost' => '10.99',
        'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
    );

    // Register the rate
    $this->add_rate( $rate );
}
```

Full code:

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Trucking shipping
Plugin URI: http://abdhannan.com
Description: Trucking shipping dengan JNE dsb
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Abd Hannan
Author URI: http://abdhannan.com
*/

/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is active
 */
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    function trucking_shipping_init() {
        if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method' ) ) {
            class WC_trucking_shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
                /**
                 * Constructor for your shipping class
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function __construct() {
                    $this->id                 = 'trucking_shipping_method'; // Id for your shipping method. Should be uunique.
                    $this->method_title       = __( 'JNE TRUCKING' );  // Title shown in admin
                    $this->method_description = __( 'Pengiriman dengan truck JNE' ); // Description shown in admin

                    $this->enabled            = "yes"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced enabled
                    $this->title              = "JNE TRUCKING"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced.

                    $this->init();
                }

                /**
                 * Init your settings
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @return void
                 */
                function init() {
                    // Load the settings API
                    $this->init_form_fields(); // This is part of the settings API. Override the method to add your own settings
                    $this->init_settings(); // This is part of the settings API. Loads settings you previously init.

                    // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
                    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
                }

                /**
                 * calculate_shipping function.
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @param mixed $package
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
                    $rate = array(
                        'id' => $this->id,
                        'label' => $this->title,
                        'cost' => '10.99',
                        'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
                    );

                    // Register the rate
                    $this->add_rate( $rate );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'trucking_shipping_init' );

    function add_trucking_shipping_method( $methods ) {
        $methods['trucking_shipping_method'] = 'WC_trucking_shipping_Method';
        return $methods;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_trucking_shipping_method' );
}
```

The problem is in `calculate_shipping`, I don't know how to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a code question, rather a 'how do I use WooCommerce' question. What you are looking for is functionality Automattic deliberately removed from WooCommerce so that they could charge for it, look [here](https://woocommerce.com/products/table-rate-shipping/) for the plugin.

If you are frugal and reduce your product weights down to a specific set, then all you really need is flat rate shipping assigned to postal code defined shipping zones, mixed with shipping classes and boom no programming ever needed.

Koda

Comment: yes, thats right, and i have use table rate plugin, but, i have to create for all shipping zone, there many zhipping zone in my country (500 more), 

so, i want shipping method automatically calculate the condition, and the data get fom json file for ex.

any one can help me, please ?

Comment: If you are trying to implement 500 shipping zones then you are doing something wrong. You should always try your best to simplify shipping every time. For example for postal codes you should use ranges.

Comment: Hmmm, you are right 
imposible to make my own plugin with the requirement ? if there is a reference paste here,  please.

Comment: You will just end up re-coding table rate shipping buddy, would be far easier to just use what is available and works.

Comment: Ok,
i will use table rate shipping, thank you @Kodaloid

Comment: Hint, google table rate, there are some cheaper options out there.